# Ordered logit in JAGS

Tags: logistic, jags

I am trying to code a simple model with JAGS:

```
set.seed(123)
x1 <- rnorm(100) 
x2 <- rnorm(100)
z <- 1.0 + x1*0.1 - x2*0.5 + rnorm(100)
y <- z
y[z < 0] <- 1
y[z >= 0 & z < 1] <- 2
y[z >= 1 & z < 1.5] <- 3
y[z >= 1.5] <- 4

jagsdf <- list(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2)
params <- c("alpha","beta")

mcmcmodel <- jags.model(file="ordlog.jag",data=jagsdf,n.chains=3)
```

with **ordlog.jag** as follows:

```
model{
    for(i in 1:100){
        mu[i] <- beta[1]*x1[i] + beta[2]*x2[i]

        logit(Q[i,1]) <- alpha[1]-mu[i]
        p[i,1] <- Q[i,1]
        for(j in 2:3){
            logit(Q[i,j]) <- alpha[j]-mu[i]
            p[i,j] <- Q[i,j] - Q[i,j-1]
        }
        p[i,4] <- 1 - Q[i,3] 

        y[i] ~ dcat(p[i,])
    } 

    ## priors over thresholds
    for(r in 1:3){
        alpha0[r] ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-3)
    }
    alpha <- sort(alpha0)

    for(j in 1:2){
        beta[j] ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-3)
    }
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in node y[3]
Observed node inconsistent with unobserved parents at initialization
```

I suspect it is due the initialization, but I could not set it properly somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, JAGS will initialize all elements of alpha0 to the prior mean 0. So the initial value of p is c(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5). Under these prior conditions, it is impossible to have y[i] equal to 2 or 3. But, in your simulated data, y[3] = 3.

The solution is to initialize the elements of alpha0 to distinct values

```
inits <- list("alpha0" = c(-0.5, 0, 0.5))
mcmcmodel <- jags.model(file="ordlog.jag", data=jagsdf, 
                        inits=inits, n.chains=3)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I think it would be great to have some simple debugging possibility wit JAGS (like browser() in R)...