# JAGS: unobserved parents and intialization

Tags: jags

I have a very simple multinomial logistic regression problem; it's a simplified version of the alligator lake/food/size BUGS example.  In my case I have (effectively) lake/food and have just stripped down the alli.bug example to handle two dimensional information: worker and IP address. There are 18 categories of 'worker' and 23 categories of 'IP address'.

Unfortunately I am getting an error

```
  Error in node X[1,1:23] Observed node inconsistent with 
                     unobserved parents at initialization
```

Granted, there is a strong possibility I've more than one bug, but I understand that this is typically associated with an initialization problem.  Unfortunately, my initialization matrices are rather large. A shotgun approach to finding appropriate values seems unlikely to succeed within a reasonable period of time.

Any hints or suggestions about possible next steps would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 
Here's the code. As I mentioned, it's just a stripped down version of the Alligator example.  I've also fiddled with the subscripts on X[i,] a bit so the error message may be slightly different (will refer to node X[1,1] rather than X[1,1:23]).

```
var
 X[I,K],      # observations I=no of workers=18, K=no of jobs=23
 n[I],        # total for each covariate pattern
 E[I,K],      # fitted values
 OlogOE[I,K], # O log O/E
 G2,            # goodness-of-fit statistic
 phi[I,K],    # exp (beta[k] ' x[i,j])
 p[I,K],      # fitted probabilities
 alpha[K],      # factor for jobs = 2,...,23
 beta[I,K],     # factor for workers = 2,...,18  for each job
 b[I,K];         # factor for workers = 2,..,,18, relative to job 1, centred
model {
# PRIORS
   alpha[1] <- 0;       # zero contrast for baseline workers
   for (k in 2:K){
      alpha[k] ~ dnorm(0,0.001);  # vague priors
   }
   # Loop around jobs:
   for (k in 1:K){
      beta[1,k] <- 0;   # corner-point contrast with first worker 
   } 
   for (i in 2:I) {     
      beta[i,1] <- 0;   # zero contrast for baseline worker
      for (k in 2:K) {
         beta[i,k] ~ dnorm(0,0.001); # vague priors
      }
   }

# LIKELIHOOD

   for (i in 1:I) {                 # loop around workers
      for (k in 1:K) {           # loop around jobs
   # Multinomial response
         X[i,k] ~ dmulti(p[i,k] , n[i]);
            p[i,k]        <- phi[i,k] / sum(phi[i,]);
            log(phi[i,k]) <- alpha[k] + beta[i,k];
         }
      }  

# FITTED VALUES
   for (i in 1:I) {     # loop around worker
         for (k in 1:K) {     # loop around jobs
            E[i,k] <- p[i,k] * n[i];
            OlogOE[i,k] <- X[i,k] * log( X[i,k] / E[i,k] );
         } 
   }
   G2 <- 2 * sum( OlogOE[,] );
}
```

Comment: Try not initializing the parameters for that node (which may be all the parameters in the model) and let JAGS pick the initial values for you; if it fails, we can think of something else.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I tried that. I also tried a few different SEED values. Finally, I'm not sure how relevant it is, but I should mention that my data matrix X[,] is very sparse (mostly 0's) - which may give me problems later.

Comment: If your code isn't too long, could you post it?

Comment: is the etiquette to add it as an edit to the original post or to post it in comments?

Comment: Adding to the original post is fine.  If you want, you can type "Edit: I've added the code below." or some such.

Comment: All your `n[i]` are > 0?  (just checking...)

Comment: If your data matrix is very sparse, you may want to recode your model using so-called nested indexing.

Comment: There are only two parameters, alpha and beta. The error message means that your initialization is doing something that is mathematically impossible or implausible. For one, alpha and beta are normal and very wide, but their sum determines a logarithm. If they're very negative, that could cause computational problems. Try initializing them to be positive only.

Comment: @jbowman : all n[i] >= 0

Comment: @JackTanner : all alpha and beta were initialized to zero . I tried various other values >= 0 and it didn't seem to make any difference. Yes, the data matrix in this case is very sparse (but this is not always the case). But I'll look into the nested indexing.

Comment: Will `n[i]=0` in `dmulti` cause problems?  I don't know, just suggesting.

Comment: @jbowman (travelling) thought it might also, but I recall that the alligator problem had at least n[i]=0. Regardless, I'll check it when I get to my computer again. Ill just generate a pseudo data set with all positives (eg all n[]=1). If it works i may also be able to use the results as inits. Thanks to you and Tanner for the suggestions.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/17121/5509

Comment: @Curious I (think) I have tried this, but will revisit. FWIW- I had to table the entire project, but it might be a good time dig it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The next step with this particular error message should (always ?) be to check the specific node mentioned in the error message and its parents.  This sounds like a lot of work when you have large matrices of initial values but the point is that you are likely making a small number of mistakes in generating those values.  Each time you trace the error message to a particular problematic node you will be able to eliminate at least one mistake and fix a lot of bad initial values.

In this case your model is simple enough that having alpha/beta initialized to all zeros should take care of most problems. If alpha/beta are zero then the derived values for phi/p would be consistent with all non-negative X's which means the only inconsistency left is that sum(X[i,]) != n[i]...